# How to append a text file on SFTP server using SharpSSH or SSH.NET library

Tags: c#, .net, sftp, ssh.net, sharpssh

I use Tamir.SharpSSH library to make my SFTP operations. I can upload file from client, delete or list files located in an SFTP server directory.

But I cannot find how to append a text file. I don't want to overwrite or delete the existing and upload a new one. I have a log file on that SFTP server. I have to add new lines to that file from client side.

I just searched the internet and looked different functions in the code but tried nothing to execute because I could not find anything till now.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

I decided to use Renci.SshNet library because of @Martin Prikryl's advise. I tried the above operations with that library also and I saw it works good. Also appending text to a text file is very simple with that library. I'm sharing a small example about that here:

```
using System
using Renci.SshNet;

namespace SFTPConnectSample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AppendText(@"/targetFolder/targetFile.txt");
        }

        private static void AppendText(string targetFilePath)
        {
            int portNumber = 22;

            using (SftpClient sftp = new SftpClient("myHostName", portNumber, "sftpUser", "sftpPassword"))
            {
                sftp.ConnectionInfo.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30);
                sftp.Connect();
                sftp.AppendAllText(targetFilePath, "\r\nThis is a new line for target text file.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, do not use SharpSSH. It's an abandoned project, not updated for years.

You can use [SSH.NET library](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET) instead.

Its `SftpClient` class has couple of methods you can use:

```
public StreamWriter AppendText(string path)
public void AppendAllText(string path, string contents)
public void AppendAllLines(string path, IEnumerable<string> contents)
```

---

If you must use SharpSSH for some reason, use:

```
SftpChannel.get(fromFilePath, toFilePath, monitor, ChannelSftp.APPEND);
```